# reverse axis in ASP.NET chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am working on code in which i want both the axis reversed. My code is

```
Dictionary<int, string> employees = new Dictionary<int, string>();
employees.Add(5, "Sell");
employees.Add(4, "Your Manegers");
employees.Add(3, "Your Peers");
employees.Add(2, "Your Direct Reports");
employees.Add(1, "Others");

Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
Chart1.Series[0].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

Chart1.Series[0].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
//Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsReversed = true;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsReversed = true;
Chart1.Series[0].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```

I want output like this:

[graph http://www.hfi.com/images/graph.png](http://www.hfi.com/images/graph.png)

Comment: Did you have a look at the samples?  http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Comment: @Erno: Yeah, not able to figure out how to reverse the coordinate system.